# Principal Value integral: Singularity Problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to calculate the Principal Value of the following integral $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ as

```
Integrate[E^(-x)/x,{x,0,∞},PrincipalValue->True]
```

But it gives $∞$. The integral by itself is singular at $x=0$, but PrincipalValue option should take care of that. Also, both functions ($e^{-x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$) converges at infinity. What is the problem?

Comment: I _think_ this only works on definite integrals. i.e. when the limits are actual values. You have $\infty$ on one limit.  Try `Integrate[1/x, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, PrincipalValue -> True]` and you'll get same error. Now change $\infty$ to an actual number, no matter how large, then it will work.

Comment: May be documentation should be more clear on this. I feel Mathematica help pages sometimes are too brief, as if they were written in a hurry :)

Comment: I think I know why it does not work for `1/x`. It found the antidetivative to be `log(x)` which at $x=\infty$ blows up. This is before looking at `PrincipalValue->True`

Comment: The integral under consideration diverges in both (traditional and principal  value) senses because of the singularity $1/x$ at the origin. Mathematica reports that.

Comment: Usually you have the singularity *within* the interval of integration for a CPV integral, e.g. `Integrate[1/x, {x, -2, 5}, PrincipalValue -> True]` or `Integrate[E^(-x)/x, {x, -2, ∞}, PrincipalValue -> True]`...

Comment: @J.M. you say `Usually you have the singularity within the interval of integration`. I actually checked this, but then why it does not work for `Integrate[1/x, {x, -2, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]` ?

Comment: @Nasser, it diverges actually (recall [Gabriel's horn](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GabrielsHorn.html)), but I find it odd that *Mathematica* gives no warning at all in this case.

Comment: I don't understand. The principal value is employed to take care of the singularity. For example, if you calculate the principal value of $e^{-x}/(x-1)$ ovr 0 to infinity, it gives a definite number. But it does not for $e^{-x}/x$. What is so special about the latter?

Comment: Well, the singularity in your first case is inside ($0<1<\infty$). Consider falling back to [the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation) to see for yourself if what you want is sensible.

Comment: @J. M. How about this one: $e^{-x}/\sqrt{x}$. Like the original integral it is singular at $x=0$. But the integral is definite.

Comment: The singularity at the left endpoint in that case is integrable, without needing Cauchy; but, more clearly, letting $x=u^2$ still gives a reasonable integral.